# OpenRC Bluetooth

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, bluetooth, bluez, openrc

I recently switched to OpenRC and cannot seem to find any up-to-date information on how to get bluetooth working. Most things on the Arch Wiki seem to be focused around systemd and PulseAudio.

Currently my Bluetooth headphones connect but do not pair with Blueman giving the error "protocol not available"

In particular, I am wondering if it is necessary to use PulseAudio or is there an alternative that will allow bluetooth to work? Is there a clear guide where I can read up on how bluetooth works with openrc?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

There is a Bluez-alsa thing on github: https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa

But I have never come across someone who actually uses this without pulseaudio.

It seems like someone with some serious knowledge of bluetooth would have to work really hard to make this work. Not accepting my own answer because I am stil lnot 100% sure if there isn't a better answer.